# What is the best way to manage Firebase user across Ionic Tabs

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic1 tabs application using Firebase for the Authentication part and the Realtime Database.

What is the best way / best practices to manage user across the tabs.

Assuming all pages/tabs must be accessible only if user is authenticated.

Do you have any recommandation or documentation?

Where to put the UserStateChange listener? Should I implement a isAuthenticated control in routes.js? etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted the following tutorial, eventually: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/add-ionic-platform-authentication-to-your-ionic-app#step1

If it can be of any help for someone else.